# Finding inverses of a function which maps ordered pairs of positive integers onto the positive integers.

Tags: inverse, elementary-functions

The function $f(x,y) = \frac{(x+y-1)(x+y-2)}{2} + y $ is a bijection which maps ordered pairs of positive integers onto the positive integers. I would like to find the functions $g$ and $h$ such that $g(f(x,y)) = x$ and $h(f(x,y)) = y$.

Through examination of a table of values, I noticed that if $t$ is the largest triangular number less than $f(x,y)$ then $f(x,y) - t = y$, and if $T$ is the smallest triangular number greater than or equal to $f(x,y)$ then $T - f(x,y) + 1 = x$. This would reduce the original problem to finding functions for $t$ and $T$, but I am not sure if this is possible.

Any tips/hints would be very appreciated! I am also curious about more generic/algebraic approaches to this type of a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x,y) 
= \frac{(x+y-1)(x+y-2)}{2} + y
= \frac{(x+y)^2-3(x+y)+2}{2} + y
= \frac{u^2-3u+2}{2} + y
=g(u, y)
$
where
$u = x+y$.

Since
$1 \le y \le u-1$,
$1+\frac{u^2-3u+2}{2}
\le g(u, y)
\le u-1+\frac{u^2-3u+2}{2}
$.
Therefore
$g(u, y)
\le \frac{u^2-3u+2+2(u-1)}{2}
= \frac{u^2-u}{2}
$
and
$g(u+1, y)
\ge 1+\frac{(u+1)^2-3(u+1)+2}{2}
= \frac{u^2+2u+2-3u-3+2+1}{2}
= \frac{u^2-u+2}{2}
= \frac{u^2-u}{2}+1
$.

Therefore
$g(u+1, 1)
=g(u, u-1)+1
$,
so there is no overlap
in the $g$ values
between
$u$ and $u+1$.

So,
for any particular index $n$,
find the unique $u$
such that
$\frac{u^2-u}{2}+1
\le n
\le \frac{u^2-u}{2}+u-1
$.
Then
$x+y = u$,
$y = n-u$,
and
$x=u-y$.

To find $u$ from $n$:

From the first inequality,
$u^2-u \le 2n-2$
or
$4u^2-4u+1 \le 8n-7$
or
$2u-1 \le \sqrt{8n-7}$
or
$u \le 1+\frac12\sqrt{8n-7}$,
or
$u \le 1+\lfloor\frac12\sqrt{8n-7}\rfloor$.

From the second inequality
$n \le \frac{u^2-u}{2}+u-1$
or
$8n \le 4u^2-4u+8u-8
=4u^2+4u-8
=4u^2+4u+1-9
$
or
$8n+9 \ge (2u+1)^2$,
or
$2u+1 \ge \sqrt{8n+1}$,
or
$u \ge  \frac12(\sqrt{8n+1}-1)$,
or
$u \ge  \lceil\frac12(\sqrt{8n+1}-1)\rceil$.

Comment: Fantastic. I had just found the 'triangular root' equation and came up with the exact same formula! Funny how your algebra aligned identically. Thanks!

Comment: Great minds think alike.

Answer (score 1):

As we have freedom to choose $y$ why don't we choose the biggest $n$ s.t. $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\lt f(x,y)$ and choose $y = f(x,y)- \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, by construction $y\gt 0$, let's prove there exists $x \in \mathbb{N}$ for this $y$ satisfying the equation. 
 From construction we know that $\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} \ge f(x,y)$. Then $ y \le \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2}=n+1$, $n = x+y-2$ so if we plug this into inequality $y \le x+y-1 => x \ge 1$. Therefore, we have found desired $(x,y)$. 
Now the question is how to find $n$. This is easier part, we can solve quadratic equation $n^2+n-2f(x,y)=0$, then take $p=\lfloor n1\rfloor$ of positive solution of the equation. $y = f(x,y) - \frac{p(p+1)}{2}$ and $x=p-y+2$.

If I am not mistaken in my calculations $p = \lfloor \frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8f(x,y)}}{2} \rfloor$

Answer (score 1):

Based on the observation of tabulated values of $f(x,y) = \frac{(x+y−1)(x+y−2)}{2}+y$, $f(x,y)$ could be interpreted as the sum from $1$ to $u = x+y-2$ with an added $y$

$$f(x,y) = \frac{u(u+1)}{2}+y$$

That gives us $h(f(x,y)) = f(x,y) - \frac{u(u+1)}{2}$ when we solve for $y$.

For $g(f(x,y))$, substitute the last $y$ with $u-x+2$ and we get $g(f(x,y)) = \frac{u(u+1)}{2}+u-f(x,y)+2$ when we solve for $x$.

For any given $x$ and $y$, $\frac{u(u+1)}{2} \lt \frac{u(u+1)}{2}+y \le \frac{(u+1)(u+2)}{2}$ or $\frac{u(u+1)}{2} \lt f(x,y) \le \frac{(u+1)(u+2)}{2}$, which means if we solve for $u$ in $\frac{u(u+1)}{2} \lt f(x,y)$ and take the ceiling, we should end up with $u+1$ for all values of $x$ and $y$.

$$\frac{u(u+1)}{2} \lt f(x,y) => u \lt \sqrt{2f(x,y) + \frac{1}{4}} - \frac{1}{2} => u+1 = \lceil \sqrt{2f(x,y) + \frac{1}{4}} - \frac{1}{2} \rceil => u = \lceil \sqrt{2f(x,y) + \frac{1}{4}} - \frac{1}{2} \rceil -1$$

We now have $u$ in terms of $f(x,y)$ and can solve $g(f(x,y))$ and $h(f(x,y))$.